# Why pressure and temperature decreases along the length of a convergent nozzle?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design, rocket, aerospace

I know that the pressure and temperature follows stagnation relations of pressure and temperature as well as area mach relation inside a convergent nozzle along the length. And according to that equation, it forms a curve that represents the pressure anf temperature. But I want to know why it is happening?  Why pressure and temperature decreases along convergent nozzle?  Like what physics it follows?  What theory it follows?  What law?  According to what effect this is happening?

Comment: See [How do diffusers turn velocity into pressure?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33181/3201), if's for a divergent nozzle, so you just need to take of the opposite reasoning. Also see this page: [Pressure is inversely proportional to area. Then why is this pressure decreased in convergent nozzle.](https://howthingsfly.si.edu/ask-an-explainer/convergent-nozzle-there-increase-velocity-and-decrease-pressure-we-know-pressure-in). If your question is different, then please give more details.